# How can I configure Android to login to an ISA proxy server?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, networking, proxy

I see that if I did a long touch over a Wifi network, I can specify some proxy settings. In my company we use a Isa Proxy server, and each user has to login through domain server.

Is there any way to configure that on our tablets? ( Android 4.1)

Comment: How is that login done manually? Is it a so-called "captive portal", where you login via web browser?

Comment: nop. It is our company network wifi. We connect yo internet through isa proxy server I think, using proxy server ip, 8080 port and our domain user and password

Comment: Ah, I see. Android 4.1, huh? Try long-press the corresponding AP in your network list, chose "edit", enable "advanced". Fill in your proxy configuration. Check if that solves your issue, and please report back; if that did the trick, I will set up a corresponding (and more detailed) answer.

Comment: Yap, I tried that but there is no place to setup the domain username and password.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is your device rooted? Then you might want to take a look at [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid). Another thing worth a try is using `user:pass@proxyserver` for the server address (e.g. if the proxy is `10.11.12.1`, user joe, password foo: `joe:foo@10.11.12.1`) -- this is how it works in some browsers for password-protected urls. If that does not work, another page worth reading on the issue is [Android-Proxy.Blogspot.DE](http://android-proxy.blogspot.de/) (don't be irritated by .DE, it's in English).

Comment: ProxyDroid works perfectly but you have to be root. I also try with user:pass@proxyserver and seems to work (without proxy droid) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I converted my comment into an answer, so you can "accept" it and other users can identify this post as "issue with a solution" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions. As you have Android 4.x, long-pressing on a WiFi APN in *Settings→Networks & Wireless→WiFi* lets you edit an APN. Check the "Advanced" box, and you can configure the proxy. Though this form does not offer separate fields for username/password, here's a trick how to do it:

For the server name, enter `user:pass@proxyserver` (e.g. if the proxy is `10.11.12.1`, user joe, password foo: `joe:foo@10.11.12.1`) -- this is how it works in some browsers for password-protected urls. In case this makes trouble (should not, but who knows), further details can be found at [Android-Proxy.Blogspot.DE](http://android-proxy.blogspot.de/) (don't be irritated by .DE, it's in English).

Another possibility would require your device to be rooted: [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) offers some comfort in connection with proxies. Next to supporting multiple profiles, it is also capable of handling different authentication methods.

Comment: The WiFi APN won't allow me to save any changes to the proxy when there is a '@' character in the server name. I'm using Android version 4.1.1.

Comment: What has an "@" sign to do in a server name? I'm not 100% sure (would need to check that with the corresponding RFC), but I don't think it should be there. Could cause confusion if that server shall act as part of an email address: `johndoe@m@il.example.com`: Which part is the user, and which part the server name here? I'm tempted to say it's the fault of the person naming that server ;)

Comment: Sorry, I meant doing `user:pass@proxyserver` does not work for me when setting up the proxy in Android. It won't allow me to save the modified WiFi settings when I type that in the server name field ("Save" is faded out). When I remove the '@' symbol, then it allows me to save the settings.

Comment: Ah, OK. First time I hear that. If there are no dedicated fields for user/pass, I have no idea what to do in such a case then, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Drony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony) application to authenticate with your proxy.

Comment: Would you mind including a link to the app you're recommending? I cannot find any app with that name.